# Can I solve this equation, that always gives me square root?

Tags: trigonometry

I have this equation:

[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCp5V.png)

I need to solve it for **b**, so I can square it:

[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32ATX.png)

and use:

[Fig.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpwDu.png)

But problem is, that I still have a square root there and I can't do anything more than just square it over and over again.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format formulas. Images, or links to images, are not searchable and harder to use in responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not square, but rewrite in the form

$$p\cos b=q\sin b$$ or $$\tan b=\frac pq.$$

Comment: Cool, it works!